# arrays vba - type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue with passing an array to a sub (receiving type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected). I have worked with array structures in other languages and I must be missing something here in vba since I can't get this to work. I have posted code snippets below for comment:

```
Private Sub x()
    Dim ssn_vals(1 To 9) As String
    Dim ssn_cells(1 To 9) As String

    'define employee object
     Dim emp As Employee

     'create new employee foreach row
      Set emp = New Employee

    'ssn values
        ssn_vals(1) = cell.Offset(0, 60)
        ssn_vals(2) = cell.Offset(0, 61)
        ssn_vals(3) = cell.Offset(0, 62)
        ssn_vals(4) = cell.Offset(0, 63)
        ssn_vals(5) = cell.Offset(0, 64)
        ssn_vals(6) = cell.Offset(0, 65)
        ssn_vals(7) = cell.Offset(0, 66)
        ssn_vals(8) = cell.Offset(0, 67)
        ssn_vals(9) = cell.Offset(0, 68)



        'ssn cell addresses
        ssn_cells(1) = cell.Offset(0, 60).Address
        ssn_cells(2) = cell.Offset(0, 61).Address
        ssn_cells(3) = cell.Offset(0, 62).Address
        ssn_cells(4) = cell.Offset(0, 63).Address
        ssn_cells(5) = cell.Offset(0, 64).Address
        ssn_cells(6) = cell.Offset(0, 65).Address
        ssn_cells(7) = cell.Offset(0, 66).Address
        ssn_cells(8) = cell.Offset(0, 67).Address
        ssn_cells(9) = cell.Offset(0, 68).Address

        emp.setSSN = ssn_vals
        emp.setSSN_cells = ssn_cells

        'validate ssn
        emp.validateSSN (ssn_vals)

end sub
```

i have a sub defined inside employee class

```
'validate SSN
Public Sub validateSSN(ssn() As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer
    'Dim orig_array(1 To 9) As Variant
    Dim multipler_array(1 To 9) As Integer
    Dim summation_array(1 To 9) As Integer


    multipler_array(1) = 1
    multipler_array(2) = 2
    multipler_array(3) = 1
    multipler_array(4) = 2
    multipler_array(5) = 1
    multipler_array(6) = 2
    multipler_array(7) = 1
    multipler_array(8) = 2
    multipler_array(9) = 1



    If Me.getSinOrT = "sin" Then
        For i = LBound(ssn(i)) To UBound(ssn(i))
           summation_array(i) = (Int(ssn(i)) * Int(multipler_array(i)))
           Debug.Print summation_array(i)
    Next i

    Else


     End If

 End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this trivial thing would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: It should be `emp.validateSSN ssn_vals` without parentheses and the routine needs to take a String array, not Variant. Since you already set the SSN as a property of the employee, I'm not sure why you need to pass the array again to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **cell** as a Range, but have not *Dim*'ed it or *Set* it.  There may be other problems

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the useful comments - this had made me realize that I didn't have to pass ssn array again to employee object, since its data was saved inside Employee already. To correct issue I created a method within Employee that verified SIN based on an Employee's existing SIN. Thanks a bunch...